# <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page that has pageblock table on it which displays data from a list. I am trying to add a field from that list as a input field but I get the below error for the quantity field. How can I use a field from a list of non sObject as input field ?

```
<apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.
```

Code : Controller

```
public class TestController_NWL{
public class OrderProduct{
    public String materialNumber {get; set;}
    public Integer quantity {get; set;}
}
Public List<OrderProduct> orderProductsList {get; set;}
}
```

VF Page :

```
<apex:page controller="TestController_NWL">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Products" columns="1">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!orderProductsList}" var="op" title="Products">
        <apex:column headerValue="Material Number">
            <apex:outputLink onclick="alert('Success');">
                {!HTMLENCODE(op.materialNumber)}
            </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Material Number">
            <apex:inputField value="{!op.quantity}" />
        </apex:column>                  
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: I think , You can't use wrapper class variable in inputfield.  <apex:inputfield> values must be a field from sobject. You can initiate a sobject in wrapper class if you want to use its in <apex:input> field.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have a sObject in this case. I can create a dummy object with all these fields but it will be a waste as it would never have any data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not an sObject field, you have to use one of the typed input tags. In your case, you would use `<apex:inputText>`.

Additional options include `<apex:inputcheckbox` and `<apex:inputTextArea>` to handle other data types.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks for the quick response : )

Comment: Note that `inputtext` will always transmit a string value of zero length to the controller even if the user left the field empty on the form. This contrasts to `inputField` wherein no entry by the user sends null to the sobject field in the controller.